# Unable to resolve ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate key name 'index_users_on_email'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, migration

This is my migration file and scheme.

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :name
      t.string :email, index: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

```
  create_table "users", charset: "utf8mb4", collation: "utf8mb4_bin", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "name"
    t.string "email"
    t.index ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email"
  end
```

I want to add unique index to users on email column.

```
class AddUniqueIndexForUsersOnEnail < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_index(:users, :email, unique: true)
  end
end
```

But, I cannot add unique index because of the error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Duplicate key name 'index_users_on_email'`.

I want to solve this problem without rolling back or dropping the database, but keeping the existing records.

If you know how to solve this problem, please let me know.

Comment: You cannot add a unique index in a column that already contains non-unique records

Comment: It's a bit too late to add the index if your table has duplicates. The best solution is to go over the table, remove the duplicates then run the migration.

Comment: There are no duplicte record. But I cannot add unique index on email column.

Comment: You already have an index named `index_users_on_email`, drop it first then re-add it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this?

```
class AddUniqueIndexForUsersOnEnail < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_index :users, :email, name: 'some_name', unique: true
  end
end
```